# MySQL fulltext search only works in BOOLEAN Mode. How get relevancy?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean, full-text-search

I want to search in Natural Language Mode to order results by relevancy, but my query only works with BOOLEAN Mode selector. If I use the query without BOOLEAN I get no results. Any idea why this does not work? Or idea how to get results by relevancy (most matched keywords first) with BOOELAN?

My query:

```
SELECT *,
MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM 
meta_data AS md 
INNER JOIN
sites AS si ON md.domain = si.domain && si.domain != '$data[domain]'
WHERE
MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score Desc
LIMIT 25
```

Database is `MyISAM` and I have altered mysql table for fulltext search

```
FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`description`,`keywords`)
```

Comment: afaik you cannot get relevancy in boolean mode , even the name suggest that it will return true or false

Comment: this is what you need : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: I tried WITH QUERY EXPANSION but this also shows no results. Still no idea why search in natural language mode does not work.

Comment: I figured out that the script I'm using fetching data with PDO:          $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  might this be reason why fulltext search in natural language mode does not work?

Comment: it can be ... just try without PDO and see

Comment: OK, after activating error messages it showed these errors: Warning: PDO::query() [pdo.query]: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list in ...
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchall() on a non-object in …   Might there be a problem with fulltext index in DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to

```
 SELECT *, MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]') AS score
 FROM 
 meta_data AS md 
 INNER JOIN sites AS si ON md.domain = si.domain && si.domain != '$data[domain]'
 WHERE
 MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 ORDER BY score DESC
 LIMIT 25
```

The

```
MATCH(md.keywords) AGAINST('$meta[keywords]') AS score
```

will return the relevancy score of the search term and

```
 ORDER BY score DESC
```

will display your results in descending order (i.e. highest score first)

Comment: OK, I figured it out: Table for fulltext indexing should not be altered for all columns. Just for the columns mentioned in the MATCH clause. So after using: ALTER TABLE meta_data ADD FULLTEXT (keywords) it works now!

Comment: That's nice to hear :)